# Is there a way in c# where I can sign a Jwt with a key I created on linux using openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048

Tags: c#, openssl, jwt

created the private key with the following command

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
```

In c# console app tried the following:

```
string keyFile = Path to keyFile
var secret = File.ReadAllText(keyFile);
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSsaPssSha256);                 
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(                
claims: claims, expires:DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), signingCredentials: creds);
token.Header.Add("kid", "7fab807d-4988-4012-8f10-a77655787450");
var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

The WriteToken throws the following error message

```
System.NotSupportedException
  HResult=0x80131515
  Message=IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider.
Algorithm: 'PS256', SecurityKey: '[PII of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'
 is not supported. The list of supported algorithms is available here: https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms
  Source=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures, Boolean cacheProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean cacheProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtTokenUtilities.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)
   at JwtConsole.Program.CreateSignedJwtToken() in C:\Projects\Jwt\dotnetcore-jwt-manager\JwtConsole\Program.cs:line 244
   at JwtConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\Jwt\dotnetcore-jwt-manager\JwtConsole\Program.cs:line 34
```

Please note very in-experienced developer any help greatly appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The exception shows you a list of supported algorithms, see [link](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Supported-Algorithms). The chosen algorithm you used is not supported on non-Windows systems.

You should use a different algorithm, preferably one of the [ECDSA algorithms](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Supported-Algorithms#ecdsa).

It is the line with SigningCredentials - replace the SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSsaPssSha256 by a supported algorithm as per [link](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Supported-Algorithms) - selected algorithm must be supported in both .NET Framework and .NET Standard 2.0 frameworks. The modified version of your code is below.

```
string keyFile = Path to keyFile
var secret = File.ReadAllText(keyFile);
var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256);
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(claims: claims, expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), signingCredentials: creds);
token.Header.Add("kid", "7fab807d-4988-4012-8f10-a77655787450");
var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

Comment: Hi @nestor10. Could you be more specific as to how one uses another one? I have the same issues with an ASP.NET Core 6 application deployed in a Linux CentOS / Apache environment.

Comment: Hi @user3105469, I have updated by answer. Please check.

Comment: Hi @nestor10! Thanks for the clarification, yet this does not tell me WHERE specifically I apply this? Also, do I alter the ininitiation in Program.cs any other way than like this?

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredentials().AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

Comment: Hi @user3105469, you did not specify that in the former question. Since I do not have any further details about your project, I can only assume - do you use IdentityServer on ASP.NET Core? Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377033/how-to-create-rsasecuritykey-keyid-with-identityserver4/70378001